# using python 2.7 to query sqlite3 database and getting "sqlite3 operational error no such table"

Tags: python, sqlite

My simple test code is listed below.  I created the table already and can query it using the SQLite Manager add-in on Firefox so I know the table and data exist.  When I run the query in python (and using the python shell) I get the no such table error

```
def TroyTest(self, acctno):

    conn = sqlite3.connect('TroyData.db')
    curs = conn.cursor()

    v1 = curs.execute('''
    SELECT acctvalue 
    FROM balancedata
    WHERE acctno = ? ''', acctno)
    print v1  
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 11):

When you pass SQLite a non-existing path, it'll happily open a *new* database for you, instead of telling you that the file did not exist before. When you do that, it'll be empty and you'll instead get a "No such table" error.

You are using a relative path to the database, meaning it'll try to open the database in the *current* directory, and that is probably not where you think it is..

The remedy is to use an absolute path instead:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('/full/path/to/TroyData.db')
```

You need to loop over the cursor to see results:

```
curs.execute('''
    SELECT acctvalue 
    FROM balancedata
    WHERE acctno = ? ''', acctno)

for row in curs:
    print row[0]
```

or call `fetchone()`:

```
print curs.fetchone()  # prints whole row tuple
```

Comment: I corrected path to conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\\Users\\TroyWin7\\workspace\\WxPython Tutorial\\TroyData.db')

Comment: but now I am having problems printing v1 in my code.  the result of the query should be a field that is floating type, but I think python cannot print it.  I guess it is a sqlite.Cursor.

Comment: @TroyLogan: carefully study the documentation; calling `.execute()` indeed returns the cursor, not the fetched rows.

Comment: Using `curs.fetchall()` is good enough instead writing a for loop. And totally yes, full path is needed, so consider using `os.path.abspath("TroyData.db")` instead of copypasting full paths everytime.

Comment: @erm3nda: using the cursor as an iterator lets the database driver fetch rows as needed, rather than fetch all results in one go (with the associated higher memory footprint).

Comment: @erm3nda: `os.path.abspath()` uses the current working directory *too*; that's no better than what the OP had.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Lol you're right, is not working even if the path is printed correctly from that function. Nevermind :_(

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the SQL statment. you must specify the db name and after the table name...

'''SELECT * FROM **db_name.table_name** WHERE acctno = ? '''