# How to deploy Flask app using waitress and heroku?

Tags: flask, heroku, waitress

I have deployed Flask app successfully but I am getting application error when I click on the herokuapp link. When I checked logs it shows something like this

```
2022-01-03T12:52:35.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user
2022-01-03T12:53:02.508102+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 8a785469 by user 
2022-01-03T12:53:02.508102+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user
2022-01-03T12:53:03.794631+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-01-03T12:53:07.748702+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `waitress-serve --call flaskr:create_app`
2022-01-03T12:53:09.003519+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO:waitress:Serving on http://0.0.0.0:8080
2022-01-03T12:53:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-01-03T12:54:08.177780+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-01-03T12:54:08.255635+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-01-03T12:54:08.406812+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

I have also used heroku ps:scale web=1

My Procfile includes:

```
web: waitress-serve --call flaskr:create_app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must provide the port to bind to (you cannot use the default 8080)

```
web: waitress-serve --port=$PORT --call 'flaskr:create_app'
```

Comment: I did it but ran into an error: sqlite3:operational error: no such table: post........I don't know how to connect database to my herokuapp. I am using sqlite3 locally.

Comment: Your first problem is solved, you have now another one. SQLLite works fine locally but on Heroku you need to make sure the path is always the same (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14903533/9095551). Also be aware local files (SQL Lite data too) is erased at each restart, Heroku file system is to be used for temporary data only